# Css selectors children

Tags: html, css

Below is my html. I would like to select 2nd caption(class's)child with        class name embed. `<div class="embed-container">test</div>`

I tried:

```css
.feature-row .threecolumns .caption:nth-child(2) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 relative feature-row" >
    <div class="threecolumns">
        <div class="caption caption-feature-block relative"  >
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <h4 >The Heart </h4>
                <p >We asked  ?"</p>
                <div class="embed-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="caption caption-feature-block relative " >
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <h4 >See You Tomorrow</h4>
                <p > takes top priority at A.</p>
                <div class="embed-container">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="caption caption-feature-block relative c" >
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <h4 >h4</h4>
                <p > A .</p>
                <div class="embed-container">embed2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do that without assigning id to the div ?

Comment: Sorry, question is not clear. What do you want to select here? Your code works fine as far as I can see.

Comment: Please also do update your HTML as it looks like a big mess and it's no fun at all to try reading it.

Comment: Updated the question. I would like to select <div class="embed-container">test</div> in the above .

Comment: Sorry but the class you are targeting does not use an `id`, nor targets _using_ an `id`, so I still don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. If you need to select the child .embed-container you should use this:

```
  .feature-row .threecolumns .caption:nth-child(2) .embed-container
```

It works:
http://jsfiddle.net/jraef1cu/10

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the class name after the :nth-child. Also some DIVs were not closed properly I think.

```
.feature-row .threecolumns .caption:nth-child(2) .embed-container {
        border:1px solid red;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jraef1cu/11/

Comment: Indeed they weren't, I just edited his code and there was one div not closed properly in the first of the three columns.